# Bash and Expect - ' is interrupting .sh script

Tags: bash, sh, expect

I am trying to create automatic sh script via using Expect package for automate process of installing our product. As i planning expect will catch questions while installations process is going on. But when script gets question: `Enter PushVOD database name (leave blank for default 'pushvod'):`
it's each time closing installation.
As i think problem in quotes - `'` in question: `for default 'pushvod'`

But i have no ideas how to solve it. I tryed to write `\'` in Expect expectations, also tryed ti write expectations with `*` but it didn't help. Script whatever is closing at this question.

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/bin/expect
#   
apt-get --purge remove python-pip
apt-get --purge remove python-setuptools
echo " " > /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list | echo "deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list | echo "deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list | echo "deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list | echo "deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list | echo "deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
cd /var/tmp
/usr/bin/apt-get update
apt-get --assume-yes install expect
tar xvfz XXXXXXXXXXX.tar.gz
mv /var/tmp/XXXXXXXX.deb /var/tmp/pushvod-dependencies
echo "deb XXXXXXXXXX amd64/" > /etc/apt/sources.list
aptitude update
expect -c 'spawn aptitude install dpkg-dev;
expect "Accept this solution?" {send "n\r"};
expect "Accept this solution?" {send "Y\r"};
expect "Do you want to continue?" {send "Y\r"};
expect "To continue, enter \"Yes\"\; to abort, enter \"No\":" {send "Yes\r"};
expect "To continue, enter \"Yes\"\; to abort, enter \"No\":" {send "Yes\r"}; 
interact;'
cd pushvod-dependencies
dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
echo "deb file:/var/tmp/pushvod-dependencies ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
aptitude update
expect -c 'spawn aptitude install pushvod;
expect "Accept this solution?" {send "n\r"};
expect "Accept this solution?" {send "Y\r"};
expect "Do you want to continue?" {send "Y\r"};
expect "To continue, enter \"Yes\"\; to abort, enter \"No\":" {send "Yes\r"};
expect "To continue, enter \"Yes\"\; to abort, enter \"No\":" {send "Yes\r"};
expect "Enter PushVOD database name*:" {send "pushvod\r"};
interact;'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need put whole string in expect. By default expect's `expect` command
   use glob patterns. So `Enter PushVOD database name*:` is fine. `*` will mean "some text here".
2. For quoting strings inside `expect` better to use `{}`. It's analogue of shells `''`.
3. You can use shell feature "Here Documents" for filling up files and
   running expect scripts.
4. In this command `tar xvfz XXXXXXXXXXX.tar.gz` last option must be `f`. After this option
   must be follow archive name.
5. In this command `echo "deb XXXXXXXXXX amd64/" > /etc/apt/sources.list` are you sure you want
   rewrite /etc/apt/sources.list with only this string? If not you should use `>>`.

There is code:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get --purge remove python-pip
apt-get --purge remove python-setuptools
cat << END > /etc/apt/sources.list
deb     http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb     http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb h   ttp://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
END
cd /var/tmp
/usr/bin/apt-get update
apt-get --assume-yes install expect
tar xvzf XXXXXXXXXXX.tar.gz
mv /var/tmp/XXXXXXXX.deb /var/tmp/pushvod-dependencies
echo "deb XXXXXXXXXX amd64/" > /etc/apt/sources.list
aptitude update
expect << END 
    spawn aptitude install dpkg-dev
    expect {Accept this solution?} {send "n\r"}
    expect {Accept this solution?} {send "Y\r"}
    expect {Do you want to continue?} {send "Y\r"}
    expect {To continue, enter "Yes"; to abort, enter "No":} {send "Yes\r"}
    expect {To continue, enter "Yes"; to abort, enter "No":} {send "Yes\r"}
    interact
END
cd pushvod-dependencies
dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
echo "deb file:/var/tmp/pushvod-dependencies ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
aptitude update
expect << END
    spawn aptitude install pushvod
    expect {Accept this solution?} {send "n\r"}
    expect {Accept this solution?} {send "Y\r"}
    expect {Do you want to continue?} {send "Y\r"}
    expect {To continue, enter "Yes"; to abort, enter "No":} {send "Yes\r"}
    expect {To continue, enter "Yes"; to abort, enter "No":} {send "Yes\r"}
    expect {Enter PushVOD database name*:} {send "pushvod\r"}
    interact;
END
```

Comment: Hi! i have tryed this. But it's didn't work for me. Installation all time interrupts at questions with quotes.

Comment: may be there is colors or quotes char not usual `"` but some utf symbols? You can run `expect -d << END` to check out what input you have